# how to load a website in c# console exactly like a webbrowser?

Tags: c#, console, web-crawler

I want to get website elements value from console to increase speed of crawling. I can't use `DownloadString()` because that website should be load just in a browser to show the data. I tried `DownloadString()` but the main data of site that always shows in browsers not included. also happens when I use Webbrowser in console object(`Webbrowser wb = new Webbrowser` ) but I have not any problem when use a webbrowser in windowsForm.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe AngelSharp can help in your case: https://anglesharp.github.io/docs/Examples.html